# What is the intuition behind 'mol' as a unit 'symbol'

Tags: terminology, mole, units, history-of-chemistry

Why are moles written with 'mol' as opposed to something which is easier to write with one character, or even two?

Comment: Cuz "m" is for meters and "mo" sounds kinda silly.

Comment: There are other alphabets and it doesn't necessarily have to resemble the word 'mole'; for example the unit for distance isn't 'd'

Comment: It can be of interest to some of the readers and OP. And it is not up to date. Indeed I am not ashamed to say that I still have to digest the latter changes in the International System. Perhaps one of us can Ask & Answer about the impact of the recent units definition to the Periodic Tables hanging in our room / office / lab, if any. Beside that, here is the link https://www.degruyter.com/configurable/contentpage/journals$002fci$002f41$002f3$002farticle-p50.xml

Comment: The letter $m$ is the abbreviation of the unit "meter". The two letters $mo$ are the abbreviation of the unit "month". $mL$ is the abbreviation of "milliliter". So the only way of making up an abbreviation for "mole" is writing $mol$, as ridiculous as it may look.

Comment: @Alchimista Thanks for the link. I wasn't aware that they had really promoted the mole to be a formal SI unit now.

Comment: @Karl Now ?? [The mole was made the seventh SI base unit in 1971 by the 14th CGPM.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mole_(unit))  Its definition was just updated recently.

Comment: @ Yolo. You say that the unit for distance is not $d$, and you are right. The unit for distance is "meter", with an abbreviation $m$. In the same direction, the unit for chemical amount is not "chem something". It is "mole", and it has an abbreviation $mol$.

Comment: @Maurice OTOH, I have thought until today "mol" is both the unit and the unit symbol ( like in Czech ), and that "mole" is mispelling, perhaps because of fitting English tongues better.  :-D

Comment: @ Poutnik What is the meaning of OTOH ?

Comment: @Maurice. In actual fact, mole is short for 'molecule' because it was counting the number of molecules. Despite this I don't think your reasoning works in the context of labelling efficiency. We call it Ampere (A) despite it being nothing to do with current for example.

Comment: @Maurice OTOH is the abbreviation of *on the other hand*.

Comment: @Maurice I have observed you repeatedly insert a space between @ and usedID. This leads to notification failure. E.g., I was not notified about your question regarding OTOH.

Comment: @Poutnik Sorry ! I did not know this circumstance. Is it better now ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The symbol *mol* is due to Ostwald who was a very influential and respected physical chemist more than a century ago. In German, "mole" is "Mol". It is a shortform of *Molekül*.

I believe the Internet Archive has an English translation of his historically famous book of 19th century. This is where I recall reading this. The original reference is W. Ostwald *Hand- und Hilfsbuch zur Ausführung physikochemischer Messungen*. This book is available on Google Books (pg 278). A footnote appears there:

> *Um nicht stets den schleppenden Ausdruck Gramm -Molekulargewicht brauchen zu müssen, werde ich diese Größe in der Folge kurzweg **Mol** nennen, und erlaube mir, diesen Vorschlag zur allgemeinen Annahme zu empfehlen. Man schreibt ohnedies diese Größe häufig Mol., und braucht daher nur den Punkt fortzulassen.*

*In order not to always have to use the sluggish expression gram - molecular weight, I will simply call this quantity **Mol** in the following, and allow me to recommend this proposal for general acceptance. Anyway, this quantity is often written as **Mol.**, so you only have to omit the point.*

Translated via ([www.deepl.com](http://www.deepl.com)) with some manual changes.

Answer (score 7):

The mole was promoted  to the status of "unit" in 1971

> The 14th Conférence Générale des Poids et Mesures (CGPM),
>
> considering the advice of the International Union of Pure and Applied
> Physics, of the International Union of Pure and Applied Chemistry, and
> of the International Organization for Standardization, concerning the
> need to define a unit of amount of substance,
>
> decides
>
> 1. The mole is the amount of substance of a system which contains as many elementary entities as there are atoms in 0.012 kilogram of
>    carbon 12; its symbol is "mol".
> 2. When the mole is used, the elementary entities must be specified and may be atoms, molecules, ions, electrons, other particles, or
>    specified groups of such particles.
> 3. The mole is a base unit of the Système International d'Unités.

It had been in use before that for quite some time, and I guess nobody wanted to change the symbol. Think about the ensuing confusion if you made up a new unit symbol today, that means exactly the same thing as the old one.

Comment: The mole unit  ( symbol mol , like kilogram has the symbol kg ) is not only ordinary SI unit, but 1 of 7 base SI units since 1971.

Comment: @Poutnik In the grand scheme of the cosmos, this is fairly recent though. ;)

Comment: @Martin-マーチン Like the whole science, isn't it ? :)

Comment: @Poutnik I looked it up now, and you're right of course. I distinctly remember my school teachers calling it "sort of" a unit, reasoning that it is mostly just a unitless number. And I'm sure most of my teachers had gotten their university degrees after 1971. ;-)

Comment: You may know as of 2019 some  S.I base units have been redefined [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2019_redefinition_of_the_SI_base_units?wprov=sfla1] if you are interested then go through this.

Comment: @S.MUKHERJEE that is what I meant by "I am not ashamed...." etc. It was already discussed here but the idea of a Q self Answer seems good to me. I cannot do it with specifically going through the issue.